# save image with UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum after rotation of the image

Tags: iphone

UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum() works pretty fine until I rotate image. According to condition, I would like to rotate image before it saved. But when I do, it happend to have low resolution only when it is after rotation.

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(selectedPhoto.bounds.size, self.view.opaque, 2.0);
    [self.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    myImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    if (rotate == true) {


        myImage = [myImage imageRotatedByDegrees:-90];
        UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(myImage, nil, nil, nil);
    }else {

        UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(myImage, nil, nil, nil);
    }
```

any hint please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go. Set the specific orientation on orientation. Don't forget to release the rotatedImage when using.

```
UIImage *rotatedImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithCGImage: originalImage.CGImage
                                                       scale: 1.0
                                                 orientation: UIImageOrientationLeft];
```